# Project archive with Ionic 2/3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can we make archive of whole ionic 3 project for move or save the code for future development. There are many unwanted node_modules and temp files.

Please help me.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and then install it again when the future development takes place

Comment: You can delete `node_modules` folder and when ever you want to develop just hit `npm install` command re create `node_modules` again and install all packages in node module.

Comment: What about android and ios folders? They are having many files. I have worked with src folder only.

Comment: It's platforms folder you can remove it and when ever you want to make build or run project you can add by running `ionic cordova platform add android` command.

Comment: Can you put those as an answer? @hrdkisback

Answer (score 0):

You can delete following folder

**node_modules**

You can delete `node_modules` folder and when ever you want to develop just hit `npm install` command to re-create `node_modules` again and install all `packages` in node module.

**platforms**

you can remove it and when ever you want to make `build` or `run` project you can add platforms by running `ionic cordova platform add android` and `ionic cordova platform add ios` command.